# How to initialize date FIELD IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I Wanted to initialize default `date` field in my table with `CURRENT_DATE();` well BENCH gives me errors that is not possible i heard about triggers but it seems to be a little over complicatet for that problem so is there any way to make this in such way

```
           CREATE TABLE Sprzedaz (
        Id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
        KlientId int not null,
        ProduktNumer int not null,
        Ilosc int not null,
        Cena float not null,
        Data date default CURRENT_DATE(),
        check (Data >= now()),
         ....
          );
```

Comment: When I do this, I do it with a trigger. That or I pass the date in in the INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a TIMESTAMP column with this:

```
Data TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or a DATETIME column (MySQL 5.6+):

```
Data DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

but if you want to initialize a DATE column using MySQL 5.5 you need an INSERT TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setdate_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.Data = CURDATE();
```

and maybe you need also an UPDATE trigger? Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b87c/1).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this, if you do not mind changing the `date` type, would be to use a `TIMESTAMP` and initialize it with `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Your definition would then become:

```
 CREATE TABLE Sprzedaz (
    Id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    KlientId int not null,
    ProduktNumer int not null,
    Ilosc int not null,
    Cena float not null,
    Data TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  <<<==== change this
    check (Data >= now()),
     ....
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL version 5.6.5 and above, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_DATE

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

So you can't do it with dates but you may be able to change your field to be a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME and Bobs your mothers brother!